# getPOB on a Java Object

Tags: java, debugging

This is a question about debugging technique.

At times, I would have a reference to an object, and I would very much like to know where it was created

Does anyone know why java would not add a convenient method on `java.lang.Object` called something like `getPlaceOfBirth()` which return a stacktrace showing where the object was created?

That doesn't look too difficult to implement, I suppose.

Also, how should I go about this while waiting for the Java creators to add this method, if they ever would?
(How would you normally figure out where/when an object of interest is created?)

Comment: You'll likely wait a looooong time before this gets added to Java. The answer is in the question. Create a stack trace in the constructor and keep it as a field in the object. docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getStackTrace()

Comment: Well, yeah, I don't want to have to alter the codebase while debugging!

Answer (score 2):

Make all of your objects extend an abstract class.  Perhaps add a property check to skip this logic when not debugging( i.e. `-Dmy.class.MyObjectDebugging=true` )

```
public abstract class MyObject
{
     StackTraceElements[] pob = null;
     long pobThreadID;

     public MyObject()
     {
         if( System.getProperty("my.class.MyObjectDebugging") != null )
         {
             pob = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
             pobThreadID = Thread.currentThread().getId();
         }
     }
}
```